Frequency compensated voltage divider - Stepping down 2.2V to 0.4V at 500kHz
Let me start by saying I do not have a good grounding in analog electronics, I'm very much a beginner. There is a specific problem I'm trying to solve however, which I've been stuck on for the last few days.
I have a digital signal, specifically one that was effectively a varying frequency sine wave that then got "clipped". It is 2.2V ptp, like this:

This signal is not symmetrical, nor is it currently centered around zero, as you can see in the image. Frequencies range from 196kHz to 720kHz. It is an NRZI signal, meaning data is encoded at the point where the waveform crosses zero (or at least where it's supposed to be once I center it). This means I need to preserve the rise and fall timing (IE, the edges) of the waveform as accurately as possible, or the data will be corrupted. I do not need to decode this signal or center it at this point however, I merely need to feed it into a capture device as it is, without further distortion.
The device I'm feeding it into has the front-end design shown in this schematic:

(further info on the design here if its helpful)
The output from this circuit feeds into a 10-bit ADC which samples at 40MHz. I would like to capture 60+ minutes of my signal over this device, but I have a problem of voltages. The ADC of the target device (ADS825) has a 2v ptp maximum, close to my source signal, but the front-end expects a signal in the range 0.235v to 1v (configured by dipswitches), which is fed into an OPA690 opamp prior to reaching the ADC. It is currently configured for 0.4v ptp range (dip2 on), and ideally that's how I would like to keep it. In particular I would not like to physically modify the capture device.
So in summary, my goal is to scale the 2.2v ptp signal shown above, to a 0.4v ptp signal, while noting that:

The frequency range varies between 196KHz to 720KHz
The signal is not symmetrical
There should be absolute minimum effect on the edges of each rise and fall (or bit drift will occur in decoding)
We cannot introduce varying DC bias that causes the signal to oscillate up and down at low frequency (from the varying frequency and lack of symmetry), as that will make decoding the NRZI data extremely difficult.

So I started looking at basic voltage dividers. I attempted a simple resistor voltage divider of the following form:

Where R1 = 15K and R2 = 3K, using a waveform generator to make a square wave at 500MHz 2.2v ptp, here's what I get:

As expected, I see signal distortion. According to this article:
https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/studentzone/studentzone-november-2018.html
I need to employ capacitors in parallel to compensate for this, but the article is built around a specific device and a different problem, and I've struggled to see how to relate it to my case. Additionally, I've found there's a load issue. While the signal looks happy enough on the scope in isolation, when I actually connect it to my capture device, presumably due to higher load, the captured signal almost entirely disappears, dropping to a near zero level. The following article talks about "loading" on a resistor voltage divider:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/loaded-and-unloaded-voltage-dividers
But again I struggle to see how to apply this information to my specific problem here.
Am I going about this all wrong?
What would be the most practical way to divide my 2.2v ptp analog signal to 0.4v ptp, without causing significant distortion up to 720KHz?
Any and all help appreciated.
EDIT:
Questions were asked about the circuit generating the output. Here's the source of the signal on the schematics, highlighted in red:

Q836, the immediate source of the signal, is a 2SA1037 PNP transistor, datasheet here:
https://www.tme.eu/Document/e0c65b6e0b3ccec1681b39d794523db6/2SA1037.pdf
This component doesn't do the "clipping", it's stored/generated this way. IC801 above this is is CXA1081S if it's relevant, info here:
https://wiki.console5.com/wiki/CXA1081

What is the circuit doing the "clipping"? In particular, its output impedance?

@TimWilliams I've added schematics for the source circuit, including a link to the datasheet for the source component. I can't see anything in the datasheet about impedance, maybe you can see something in there that helps?

Is the signal really some sort of balanced RLL or does it actually go all the way down to DC?

@JasenСлаваУкраїні the signal originates from an RF signal coming off a laser reading data from a CD. The signal as you see above is basically the raw RF, with some amplification and minor massaging done by the CXA1081S chip which, among other things, seems to center the signal around a stable DC level somewhere around 0.8v, and correct for AC coupling. I can capture the raw RF signal, but the AC coupling makes it hard to process due to a lack of a stable zero level. See the image here:
https://imgur.com/a/XcC33ge

The emitter-follower output stage of the "generator" is not really suitable for direct connection to any load under a few kilohms. You certainly can't attach a resistor potential divider with low enough impedance to drive the 50Ω input of the "front-end".
A buffer is in order. Since the input of your "front-end" is terminated with 50Ω and a BNC connector, I presume you are using 50Ω coax cable, and to obtain the best fidelity in signal transmission, you should take care to provide a matching output impedance from the buffer.
Here's an appropriate design:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This requires a high(-ish) bandwidth and slew rate op-amp, and I've used the LM318 here. Whatever you use must be unity-gain stable. The OPA690 has internal compensation to make it stable at unity gain, so you could probably use that too, but it's such a fast device that it might need some kind of slew-rate limiting to mitigate overshoot or ringing. If you have one spare, give it a try, but remember to to reduce supply potentials to ±6V.
The circuit also requires a dual supply, which is inconvenient but necessary if you wish to keep everything else simple, and you wish to retain signal excursions slightly below 0V. The supplies don't have to be ±12V. Check the op-amp's datasheet to find out what supply range is acceptable, and its input and output voltage limits, then choose supply potentials to suit.
The op-amp is configured as a voltage follower, a unity gain buffer, with input impedance so high that it won't influence the source signal at all. R1 and R2 form a potential divider responsible for attenuation from 2.2V pk-pk down to 0.8V pk-pk. R1 and R2 together also provide 50Ω output impedance, which when combined with the 50Ω input impedance of your "front-end", will further attenuate by a factor of two, to obtain 0.4V pk-pk at OUT.
You don't need R1 and R2 to be as precise as I've shown here. 150Ω and 82Ω would be fine, but of course you must then expect output impedance and attenuation to be affected slightly.
You are building everything inside the boxed region. R3 represents the input impedance of the "front-end" and doesn't form part of the buffer. I only included it here for the purpose of simulation, which shows what happens to a 2.2V pk-pk input (blue):

There will potentially be some sharp signal transitions at the op-amp's output, with the correspondingly sharp changes in supply current demand. Don't omit the two supply decoupling capacitors C1 and C2, and install them as physically close to the op-amp's supply pins as possible.

For completeness, and for those interested, the algebra to find R1 and R2 goes as follows:
Thevenin resistance (combined resistance in parallel) is their effective output impedance, which should be 50Ω:
$$ \frac{R_1R_2}{R_1 + R_2} = 50\Omega $$
They must attenuate 2.2V down to 0.8V:
$$ 2.2V \times \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} = 0.8V $$
That's two simultaneous equations to solve, which yields:
$$ R_1 \approx 138\Omega, R_2 \approx 79\Omega $$

You're a legend. @bobflux suggested something similar first, but your answer with a schematic (plus simulation), and a discussion of slew rate (which let me to a very valuable document here: https://sound-au.com/articles/frequency-vs-gain.htm), gave me what I needed to get this over the line. I went with the OPA690 since there were no LM318's on the continent for sale. Since it's zero-crossings I was after more than signal peaks, overshoot wasn't a problem.

Picture of the working test board, running off -5/+5 rails in the device. DC jack left from testing with a waveform generator. https://imgur.com/a/ULMm2Yu

Here's a picture of the attenuated signal on the scope. I went with the given formula for 0.8V rather than the 0.4V I was originally aiming for, since it was easy for me to adjust the gain for this on the capture device and I wanted to eliminate other variables since I was already changing the opamp. I used two resistors in series for both resistors to make the target values, since I didn't have them exactly on-hand.
https://imgur.com/a/Ok2Uk9G

@RogerSanders Nice, it's good to get feedback like this, mostly I never hear from the asker again!

You have to put a capacitor across each resistor. You can either put larger enough C to swamp any (variable) load capacitance, or compute the C accurately enough to precisely include the effects of load capacitance.
Note that your feedback loop (with variable feedback resistances) will have a similar issue with loading, and could use similar compensation.

To lower the impedances, you could attenuate at the (50 Ω) input -- e.g. by breaking the 50 Ω input R to 41 and 9 Ω. At those levels, the C loading would be insignificant.

If you attenuate at the output (actually better because this attenuates the noise also), you might use 4.1k and 0.9k. Put C in parallel with each R in the same (4.1 : 0.9) ratio -- e.g. 1 nF across the 4.1k and 1*4.1/0.9 = 4.56 nF across the 0.9 k. Note this is a non standard value, and likely C tolerances will affect the amount of correction you an achieve.
You can do a similar thing for the feedback network -- put a fixed C across R405 and calculate the individual values you need across R406..409.

Would ceramic capacitors be the right choice here, especially given those values? That helps me, because I was unsure about electrolytics and if I needed non-polarized capacitors because the voltage swings between positive and negative. Are there any implications if I use more than one capacitor in series to try and achieve the non-standard values?

Note the above assumes a (ballpark) 50 ohm source (which it appears is not the case), and that stray capacitances are dominant (which they normally aren't at such values). This seems geared more towards oscilloscope input circuitry, where resistors of 100s kohm do require capacitance for equalization.

Would decreasing R975 value substantially help? (Left hand end  of Red Line.) || Suitably capable Unity gain  buffer at output of generator allowing low values of divider resistors?

Ceramic caps don't have a particularly good tolerance. for best results use polystyrene or polypropylene caps (note these are physically much larger). OK to put ones in series (or parallel), but you don't need extreme precision.

No, the source impedance is 're' of Q826 (approximately 26mV/IE). This would only affect how the system appears as 50 Ω.

@jp314 Ceramic capacitors are available in any tolerance you're willing to pay for. C0G are economical in the low nF and below, and are commonly available in 5%. Polystyrene haven't been made in decades AFAIK and there are better (cheaper, more available) equivalents.

instead of computing in detail you can use a variable capacitor and adjust it ti make the signal look good - like how oscilloscope probles are compensated.

The data acquisition card (DAQ) is AC coupled with a highpass cutoff around 3kHz. This will result in slanting of the flat tops and bottoms of your waveform.
Then, there is an elliptic low pass filter, whose impulse response will exhibit some ringing, although the input signal doesn't seem to contain high enough frequencies for that to cause problems.
The DAQ has 50 ohm input impedance, via a resistor to ground.
The signal source is a PNP transistor with a pullup resistor, probably intended to drive a short length of PCB trace. The RF chip in the schematic takes a 2.5V supply according to the wiki, I'd assume about 1mA bias for the transistor through the 2.7k resistor, so its output impedance should be low enough, around 25 ohms, but it will depend on the transistor's bias, which depends on output voltage.
The signal source can sink strong current, being a PNP transistor, but in the other direction it's only a 2k7 pullup, so asking it to source current will probably result in the transistor turning off and a clipped waveform. From the scope shot, it appears the maximum output voltage is 1.8V, so using a voltage divider to ground will require rather high value resistors, which combined with capacitance, make it slow.
Any realistic resistance divider value (ie a few tens of kOhm) will also not be compatible with the 50 ohm resistor to ground at the input of the DAQ. That would form another divider, with way too much attenuation.
Personally I would build a small board with a buffer opamp, to be placed right at CN806 connector in the player schematic. For convenience, you'll need an opamp capable of running on the supplies from the player, fortunately these seem to be +/- 2.5V so there are a lot of options for a rail to rail opamp with >10MHz bandwidth. So, basically a postage stamp sized board with an opamp and 2 local decoupling caps.
Once the signal is buffered by the opamp you can insert an attenuator on the output with lower resistor values. I'd recommend a divider with 138R and 78R. This has an output impedance of 50R. With the 47R resistor in the DAQ input the total attenuation will be close to what's needed to turn 2.2Vpp into 0.4Vpp. The opamp will need to be able to output 15mA, which should not be an issue.
--
I missed something: C402 on the DAQ board input, in the opamp's feedback. This may cause problems by adding shelving high pass to the response around 7kHz and slant the tops and bottoms of the waveform even more:

If that's a problem you'll need to modify the DAQ board, if you do that you may as well go all the way: change the gain of the opamp to 1 to avoid having to attenuate, by removing C402. Then remove the R401 56R resistor to ground... increase C401 to 1µF... but without it the 56R termination resistor the cable should be as short as possible.

Excellent analysis. We see why knowledge of the source is important: it may have a low impedance in the small-signal case, but this will not be a small-signal scenario, and that impedance will not remain throughout the cycle if so loaded.  Personally, I would use a higher-value resistor divider (along the lines of a "min-loss pad"), AC-couple it to remove the supply bias thus incurred, and set the input stage thing to a high gain setting to compensate. Buffering needs more circuitry, but is the semantically simpler solution (don't care about source impedance).

Thanks bobflux and @TimWilliams. If I'm understanding things right, a buffer opamp (output fed into inverting input) will allow me to "decouple" concerns about load. After that I do a straight resistor divider to adjust voltage. No capacitors in parallel with the resistors, is that correct? Is that because the buffer opamp has taken care of that problem now for me? I'm looking at using an OPA690, which I have on hand, powered off internal +5v rail available from the player. Does this schematic look right?
https://i.imgur.com/di8jFjJ.png

If the opamp is powered by +5V/0V it won't be able to output the negative voltage parts of the waveform. Also OPA690 is not rail to rail neither on the input nor on the output so it would require +5/-5V supply. I missed something: C402 on the DAQ board input, in the opamp's feedback. This may cause problems by adding shelving high pass to the response around 7kHz and slant the tops and bottoms of the waveform even more.

The op-amp is rated over 300MHz GBW, input capacitance about 1pF. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa690.pdf With the filter labeled as 14MHz LPF, resistor values up to 10k or so. (More likely the amp itself would oscillate if resistor values this large were used, hence the low-100s values used in the circuit. With the exception of R406-R407, which is where the high GBW comes into play, allowing the desired gain up to 8.5 or so while keeping bandwidth over 35MHz before the filter). It seems doubtful the input signal (with a ~400ns rise time) will need the full bandwidth.
